# Exchange 2003 forward all mail for a single user to an external email address

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, mail-forwarding

I should preface this question with: I have already warned management in the strongest possible terms how bad of an idea this is. That said, I still have to get this job done.

Our environment:

- Server 2003 with a functional 2000 domain level
- Exhcnage 2003
- Outlook 2007

I've been asked to set up a forward to an outside email address for every email sent to a specific set of users. I know I could go to each user and use the Rules functions in the Outlook client to accomplish that but if at all possible I'd like to administer that from a central point. Do I have the ability to use AD or the exchange management UI to get this job done? Maybe GPO to control the client?

Since I know someone will suggest the obvious "Why not allow connectivity back to the email server via POP or IMAP." I've already been told that as a matter of policy that isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this centrally by creating Contacts for the external recipients in AD and then configuring the forwarding to these Contacts on the relevant user objects in AD.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So on the newly created AD user I would configure the default SMTP address to be a remote email address? I just assumed doing that would forward the incoming email to the mailbox of the newly created AD user rather than send it to the remote email.

Comment: No. Once you create the Contacts for the external recipients you go to the user account for the user account you want to forward the email from, access the properties pages, go to the Exchange General tab, click the Delivery Options button and set the `Forward to` to the Contact.

Comment: I just tested this. I created a new AD User. Set the primary email address to a gmail address. Then modified the forwarding to forward to the newly created AD user. It did in fact put a copy of the email into the local exchange mailbox rather than send it off to gmail. Did I miss something?

Comment: You want to forward it to an external Contact, not an AD user. You need to create a Contact, not an AD user. Then configure the forwarding options to forward to the Contact. So create ContactA then Configure UserB to forward to ContactA.

Comment: I think that is where I went wrong. I'll get that tested. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help...